# Pulling Docker Image from Docker Hub : NOt Found

Tags: daemon, docker-registry

I am using docker in windows 10.
MY docker is working properly but when i try to pull Image from docker hub via cmd:

C:\Users\pca90>docker pull hello-world Using default tag: latest Error
response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Not Found

Answer (score 0):

Just issue these commands in a terminal or command window

```
docker-machine restart default # Restart the environment 

eval $(docker-machine env default) # Refresh your environment settings
```

after running above it will work

If not then please update your question with the output from issuing

```
docker info
```

Comment: how to set this environment settings ??  Is it in Command Prompt ?

Comment: docekr info command  is proper work in my system. but when use this commond  (< docker pull hello-world >) then error in command prompt is :: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: Not Found      @also check this error screen sort in my question..